# The object passed as the value prop to the Context provider changes every render

Tags: javascript, react-usememo

I have this error:

> src/index.js   Line 9:36:  The object passed as the value prop to the
> Context provider (at line 9) changes every render. To fix this
> consider wrapping it in a useMemo hook
> react/jsx-no-constructed-context-values

I am not sure how to use `useMemo` in this case.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import FirebaseContext from './context/firebase';
import { firebase, FieldValue } from './lib/firebase';
import './styles/app.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <FirebaseContext.Provider value={{ firebase, FieldValue }}>
    <App />
  </FirebaseContext.Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: did you solve it? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 15):

I think you need to return `FireBaseContext` from another component. And in that component you can do `useMemo` to make ESLint happy.

Something like below (I didn't test this)

```
import { useMemo } from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import FirebaseContext from './context/firebase';
import { firebase, FieldValue } from './lib/firebase';
import './styles/app.css';


ReactDOM.render(
  <FireBaseWrapper />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

const FireBaseWrapper = () => {
  const fireBaseProviderValue= useMemo(() => ({ firebase, FieldValue }), [firebase, FieldValue]);

return (<FirebaseContext.Provider value={fireBaseProviderValue}>
    <App />
  </FirebaseContext.Provider>)
}
```

Comment: is this actually necessary at such a high level of the render tree? I'm going to do it to make eslint happy but wondering how necessary it really is

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and didn't necessarily want to use 'useMemo'. I instead pasted this eslint command above the line in question, and it disables the eslint flag.

```
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-constructed-context-values
```

This then allowed me to deploy without the issue.

Comment: Turning off the warning, which has a good reason for being there in the first place, is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it further with the following snippet:

```js
const FireBaseWrapper = () =>
  <FirebaseContext.Provider value={useMemo(() => ({ firebase, FieldValue }), [firebase, FieldValue])}>
    <App />
  </FirebaseContext.Provider>;
```